# Tkinter. Изменение имени изображения через нажатие кнопок.

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, классы

Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Вперёд" менялось изображение (прибавляя к переменой "Х" 1) на "Label". А при нажатии "Назад" шла проверка на отрицательные числа и меняла изображение на предыдущее.

**imglink = PhotImage(file="../Images/img".format(x)+".gif")**
**imglabe = Label(image=imglink)**

Comment: Молодой человек, объясните по-человечески алгоритм того, что вы делаете и что хотите получить. Иначе внятного ответа вы не дождетесь!

Answer (score 1):

Судя из вопроса, у вас есть некоторое количество объектов Image. Создайте словарь этих объектов.

```
image_dict = {}
for i, name_image in enumerate("путь/к/папке/изображений"):
    img = Image.open("путь/к/папке/изображений/{0}".format(name_image))
    image_dict[i] = img
```

Все. Нажали на кнопку. Установили счетчик, извлекли по нему изображение из словаря, обновили кнопку.